# I have to add two dataframes and calculate the sum for each account id

Tags: r

df1

```
acc_id || s1_2005 || s1_2006
87         1       1
```

df2

```
acc_id || s2_2005 || s2_2006
87            2       3
```

output

df3

```
acc_id ||s1_2005 + s2_2005 || s1_2006 + s2_2006
87                3                   4
```

Comment: Thank you for the information . I will keep this in mind .

Answer (score 0):

There are a a bunch of ways to do this.  One way is to use `rbind()` to stack the data together into one dataframe, and then to `aggregate()` the data to the acc_id level.

```
# example data
df1 <- data.frame(
    acc_id = c(87, 88),
    s1_2005 = c(1, 2),
    s1_2006 = c(1, 2))

df2 <- data.frame(
    acc_id = c(87, 89),
    s1_2005 = c(2, 4),
    s1_2006 = c(3, 4))

# combine data by stacking
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

# sum s1_2005 and s1_2006 by acc_id
res <- aggregate(df[ , c("s1_2005", "s1_2006")], by=df["acc_id"], FUN=sum)

# print result
res
```

The result:

```
  acc_id s1_2005 s1_2006
      87       3       4
      88       2       2
      89       4       4
```

Comment: Thank you for your response , but i need to add s1_2005 and s2_2005 for each account_id.

Comment: That is *exactly* what my code does.  I used 3 account IDs (87, 88, and 89) so you could see how the data for ID 87 were being added together.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>% 
    group_by(acc_id) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), sum), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  acc_id s1_2005 s1_2006
#   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     87       3       4
#2     88       2       2
#3     89       4       4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    acc_id = c(87, 88),
    s1_2005 = c(1, 2),
    s1_2006 = c(1, 2))

df2 <- data.frame(
    acc_id = c(87, 89),
    s1_2005 = c(2, 4),
    s1_2006 = c(3, 4))
```

Comment: Thank you very much